# perl get list of desired parameters

Tags: perl

Is there a convention to request a list of required parameters for a function?  I'd like to be able to call a subroutine which would tell me that I need to provide $phrase and $times when calling @repeat.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub repeat {
    my $phrase = shift;
    my $times = shift;
    return $phrase x $times;
    }
```

Comment: I think it was the strange wording of your first sentence that misled people. It wasn't until you commented on my answer that we realised you actually want a way of determining the prototype of a subroutine. It's an odd thing to want to do unless you're writing an IDE or something similar. Would you explain your reasons for this, as there may well be a much better solution. Standard Perl 5 doesn't have prototypes in the first place so there's nothing to fetch. You may well be better off using a different language.

Comment: Thanks, that's good feedback and I apologize for poorly phrased question.  My use case is to dynamically display required named parameters on a web page after a function has been selected.  The accepted answer of Function::Parameters is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be asking for **introspection**. There are plenty of OO frameworks which provide it (e.g. [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose)). But, if you want to be able to declare a *function* and then examine it from within your program, [Function::Parameters](https://metacpan.org/pod/Function::Parameters) is a reasonable way to go.

From the [Function::Parameters::Info](https://metacpan.org/pod/Function::Parameters::Info) Synopsis:

```
  use Function::Parameters;

  fun foo($x, $y, :$hello, :$world = undef) {}

  my $info = Function::Parameters::info \&foo;
  my $p0 = $info->invocant;             # undef
  my @p1 = $info->positional_required;  # ('$x', '$y')
  my @p2 = $info->positional_optional;  # ()
  my @p3 = $info->named_required;       # ('$hello')
  my @p4 = $info->named_optional;       # ('$world')
  my $p5 = $info->slurpy;               # undef
  my $min = $info->args_min;  # 4
  my $max = $info->args_max;  # inf

  my $invocant = Function::Parameters::info(method () { 42 })->invocant;  # '$self'

  my $slurpy = Function::Parameters::info(fun {})->slurpy;  # '@_'
```

The introspection feature in the ::Info module is actually implemented using Moose.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I will try this later. FYI, i searched "perl introspection" and didn't get great results, but did encounter this which exactly what I was looking to do (but in the wrong language) 

>>> def myfunc(arg1, arg2, arg3='toto', *args, **kw): pass
...
 >>> import inspect
 >>> inspect.getargspec(myfunc)
(['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'], 'args', 'kw', ('toto',))

Comment: You could also wait for Perl 6, or try Schwern's [Perl 5i](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/perl5i-v2.13.1/). Perl 5 just doesn't lend itself to these sorts of OO techniques out of the box -- and that's okay.

Answer (score 6):

Of course, you can build some control mechanism by yourself, depending your needs. But there are some modules to help you with subroutine signatures. I will offer 3 of them:

1. [signatures](https://metacpan.org/pod/signatures) , the simplest
2. [Kavorka](https://metacpan.org/pod/Kavorka), with type checking
3. [Method::Signatures](https://metacpan.org/pod/Method::Signatures) for OO methods

Comment: This seems to get me closer.  To clarify, is there any way to inspect a sub and return a list of desired parameters?   Signatures and parameters seem to be ways of handling parameters I've already provided.  It looks like Attribute::Signature (which I found via your answer) allows you "to define a call signature for subroutines", which I think is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Ben Grimm referred [Function::Parameters](https://metacpan.org/pod/Function::Parameters) may be then solution for inspecting?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the best solution to this question is to use [`Perl6::Parameters`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Parameters) which, as its name suggests, emulates the semantics of Perl 6 *without* the horror of using a source filter.

Comment: This sounds promising.  Will doing something like calling prototype(function) give me the back the named parameters?  If so, that answers my question.

Comment: These three modules I suggested do not use source filters too, AFAIK.